# Telerik report error Telerik.Reporting.ReportSerialization.Current.ReportSerializable

Tags: c#, reporting-services, telerik-reporting

I am getting this weird error while trying to deploy this inside a linux based docker container. Though when I run the application from visual studio in my windows machine, it works fine, but after deployment report throws this error:

```
Parameters(System.String, Telerik.Reporting.Services.AspNetCore.ClientReportSource) on controller Company.ReportAPI.Controllers.ReportsController (Company.ReportAPI).
   at Telerik.Reporting.Serialization.ObjectReader.CreateInstance(Type type, String name)
   at Telerik.Reporting.Serialization.ObjectReader.CreateInstance(Type type)
   at Telerik.Reporting.Serialization.ObjectReader.ReadObject(Type type)
   at Telerik.Reporting.Serialization.ObjectReader.ReadXmlElement(String name)
   at Telerik.Reporting.Serialization.ObjectReader.Deserialize(IResourceHandler handler)
   at Telerik.Reporting.XmlSerialization.XmlSerializerBase.Deserialize(XmlReader reader, IResourceHandler resourceHandler)
   at Telerik.Reporting.XmlSerialization.XmlSerializerBase.Deserialize(Stream stream, IResourceHandler resourceHandler)
   at Telerik.Reporting.XmlSerialization.ReportXmlSerializer.Telerik.Reporting.ReportSerialization.IXmlSerializer.Deserialize(Stream stream, IResourceHandler reso
urceHandler)
   at Telerik.Reporting.ReportPackager.UnpackageDocument(Stream packageStream)
   at Telerik.Reporting.Processing.UriReportDocumentResolver.Resolve(IProcessingContext context, UriReportSource rs)
   at Telerik.Reporting.Processing.ReportDocumentResolver`1.Telerik.Reporting.Processing.IReportDocumentResolver.Resolve(IProcessingContext context, ReportSource
rs)
   at Telerik.Reporting.Processing.ReportDocumentResolver.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<Resolve>b__0(IReportDocumentResolver r)
   at Telerik.Reporting.Processing.ReportDocumentResolver.Bind[T](IProcessingContext context, ReportSource source, Func`2 func)
   at Telerik.Reporting.Processing.ReportDocumentResolver.Resolve(IProcessingContext context, ReportSource source)
   at Telerik.Reporting.Processing.ResolvedReportDocument.ResolveReportsRecursively(ReportSource rs, IProcessingContext context, IDictionary`2 parentRsParameters,
 Boolean parentShouldDispose, List`1 result, IReportDocument& definition, ResolvedReport& tocReport, ReportBookTocPosition& tocReportPosition)
   at Telerik.Reporting.Processing.ResolvedReportDocument.Create(ReportSource rs, IProcessingContext context)
   at Telerik.Reporting.Processing.DocumentParametersManager`1..ctor(ReportSource definition, IProcessingContext processingContext, IParameterValueParser paramete
rValueParser)
   at Telerik.Reporting.Processing.DocumentParametersManager..ctor(ReportSource rs, IProcessingContext processingContext, IParameterValueParser parameterValuePars
er)
   at Telerik.Reporting.Services.Engine.ReportEngine.GetParameters(String clientID, String report, Dictionary`2 parameterValues)
   at Telerik.Reporting.Services.AspNetCore.ReportsControllerBase.GetParameters(String clientID, ClientReportSource reportSource)
   at Company.ReportAPI.Controllers.ReportsController.GetParameters(String clientID, ClientReportSource reportSource) in /app/Company.ReportAPI/Controllers/ReportsContr
oller.cs:line 27
```

Comment: What is the target framework. .NET7?

Comment: The target framework is .net core 3.1